# Why ConnectionString fails for SqlConnection using MSN example in C#?

Tags: c#, sqlconnection, northwind

I am using the following tutorial example verbatim:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.aspx

The error message is that the connection failed. "Modify it to connect to a Norhtwinf=d database accessible to your system."

```
string connectionString =
     "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" +
     "Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost";

SqlConnection northwindConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
     northwindConnection.Open();
```

As far as Northwind Database, I downloaded it from this website and I ran it.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23654

Would you be able to tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Can you add the full error message you are getting, to your question?

Comment: Have you setup SQL Server with the login details of the account running the application?

Comment: Also, make sure SQLServer is running. Right click my computer, go to manage and turn it on.

Comment: Do you definitely have Northwind as a database in SQL Server Management studio? The sample you link is for SQL 2000 - I doubt that would automatically install itself into a more modern SQL Server. Which version are you running? Can you not download the sample databases for that?

Comment: You need to tell us what the the actual Exception you are getting.  The error message you posted is not the actual exception.

Comment: Can you connect to the database using another program like Query Analyzer or the isql utility?

Comment: @JUstin Pihony:  The Connection String <Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False; 
     Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=localhost> failed to Connect.Modify it to connect to a Norhtwind database accessible to your system.

Comment: @Oded: I guess that is my problem?  I have no idea how to setup the demo database.

Comment: @PaulG: SQLEXPRESS has started. Do I need anything else?

Comment: @Rup: I am not sure. If you cn , give me a tutorial URL on what I need to do as I am new to Windows,  Visual Studio 2010 , and SQL server but I am an experienced programmer.

Comment: @user78739: I tyoed the message for Justin Pihony

Comment: If you don't already have it you should download and install [SQL Server Management Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593) (that's the 2008 version). You can then use that to connect to your SQL Server and explore it, see which databases you have available etc. [According to this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smartclientdata/archive/2005/11/02/488258.aspx) the databases were installed as backup files; you should then use management studio to restore them into a new database (easier than the command line instructions there).

Answer (score 1):

`Data Source` property needs to point to your SQL instance name, and if your SQL instance is the default one.

I know that the next suggestion is a little weird and looks like the same that you are using, but try and let me know what happened:

```
string connectionString =
     "Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;" +
     "Initial Catalog=Northwind;Data Source=.";
```

note that I've modified the Data Source value from **'localhost'** to a (dot).

Comment: can you check that your SQL instance is reachable?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the account has access to that database, and try using this connection string:

```
connectionString="Server=MACHINE-NAME\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```